# Embedding an Excel spreadsheet into Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

I tried to embed an Excel spreadsheet into a Word document (Microsoft Office 2010) but the spreadsheet does not appear in the document where I have placed the cursor/where I want it to be.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello Benda, glad to have you at SuperUser.  You might want to expand your question with a bit more detail or it will likely to be closed.

Comment: How did you try to embed the Excel spreadsheet? Please edit your question with basic step-by-step directions, so we can try to replicate your situation and provide an accurate answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open both the Word document and the Excel worksheet that contains the data that you want to create a linked object or embedded object from.
2. Switch to Excel, and then select the entire worksheet, a range of cells, or the chart that you want.
3. Press CTRL+C.
4. Switch to the Word document, and then click where you want the information to appear.
5. On the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click the arrow under Paste, and then click Paste Special.
6. In the As list, select Microsoft Office Excel object.
7. Click Paste to insert an embedded object, or click Paste link to insert a link to the object.

Those are the instructions from [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/link-or-embed-an-excel-worksheet-HA010120810.aspx).  So... did you use the Paste Special... and then selecting the Microsoft Office Excel Object option?